# Is there a getForm().createRecord() method?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Is there anything like

```
form.getForm().createRecord();
```

because there is `form.getForm().updateRecord([record]);`

I don't want `form.getForm().submit()` because I have to specify `url` attribute but when I use `.updateRecord` it uses store:

```
api: {
  create: 'link',
  update: 'link',
  delete: 'link',
  destroy: 'link',

}
```

Is there anything like `.updateRecord()` but for creating new record, not updating?

Comment: upateRecord doesn't call a proxy at all (or any url's) it just overwrites the values of your record that you loaded in your form.

Comment: Oh, I understand. store.sync() then syncronises the record. Thank you. +1 for a new information. :D

Comment: store.sync() does yeah. It will look at dirty records, deleted, created, ... If you want to create a record you can just instantiate your model and add it to your store, then sync it.

Comment: Understand. Thank you. :D If you want, put that as an aswer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a record you can just instantiate your model and add it to your store, then sync it.

Comment: Ups, same answer and it looks you was first :) so then +1

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
form.getForm().loadRecord(Ext.create('YourModelName'));
```

right after open the the form.

**Edit** *Just for the sake of completeness*

After all edits are done fetch the record

```
var rec = form.getForm().getRecord();
```

This record will most likely have dirty fields and is marked as phantom (unknown by the server)
You now have two options

Directly sync it if the Model has a proxy assigned by using **[save()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save)**

```
rec.save();
```

or add it to a store as @JohanHaest already mentioned

```
storeRef.add(rec);
storeRef.sync();
```

Comment: I understand. Thank you. I'll use the storeRef.sync(). I think it's a better solution.

Comment: Basically they can be used both. The only difference is that the store may batch operations while the Model not. I use them both